# UnexpectedValueException User must implement CanResetPassword interface

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm using laravel 6 and I'm having a problem with reset password, I dit sum research but nothing works. most of them telling me to add CanResetPassword, I have added it but still nothing.

This is my User.php class

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
   use Notifiable;

   ....
}
```

Config:Auth

I just added a new providers called password that uses eloquent. I think this might be bad practice, but its not showing the same error anymore.

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'users',
        ],
        'password' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'password',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],
```

This is how it is before I added the password provider

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'users',
        ],
        'password' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: `use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;`

Comment: @STA I have tried to add that. but nothing works.